# IntelliJ sorting todo items

Tags: intellij-idea, todo

How can I find and sort `TODO` items alphabetically, like in Eclipse?

I can't use the file-search function since I need to find only comments and not strings and literals. With the current mixture of source files/templates/scripts, TODOs already appear in at least the following manners: `//TODO`, `// TODO`, `# TODO`, `-- TODO`, `<-- TODO`, not to mention possible occurrences of `FIXME` or `IMPROVE`

The TODO-panel doesn't allow sorting or even listing occurrences in the top level of the tree structure. It seems I can only choose between Modules, Packages and Files to be top level nodes.

Comment: why you need to sort by alphabetical order?

Comment: This is a very old question which newer versions of IntelliJ have surpassed (Or I was too inexperienced with it). No need to answer this anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Normally people do not sort their TODO lists alphabetically, but rather use different ways to prioritize their work. Therefore, IntelliJ IDEA does not provide the alphabetic sorting feature. There is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7293) for this functionality, but it's not currently planned for any future release.

If you need to find a specific TODO item, you don't need to sort the list. Instead, simply click in the TODO view and start typing, and IntelliJ IDEA will locate the TODO item containing the string you've typed.

Comment: I want to take note to code for example: STEP 1, STEP 2. It is great, if they are sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that I cannot filter FIXME issues out of box, but it can be configured in IDEA. Refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-todo.html. I do not understand why it is not pre-configured ...

[image]

Then you can filter by TODO, FIXME

[image]